# (Urgent) Windows 10 reboot stuck at "Preparing Windows" with Defender trying to remove "virus"

Tags: windows, virus, reboot, windows-defender

Windows defender found a file I downloaded as a Trojan. It was Spursint.something. It said I need to reboot to remove it, so I clicked on "Reboot now". Before actually shutting down, a screen appeared saying "Preparing Windows. Do not shut down PC" (I have Windows in another language so it may not be exactly what I said) and it's now stuck there. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it stuck in this stage for longer than 3-4 hours then press and hold power button until computer will shut down. After 30 seconds turn on computer as usually.

P.S. 
When computer finish updating itself, tell you antivirus to do a full scan.
Just be on a safe side install free version of Malwarebytes and run one more scan using it.

Comment: THANK GOD IT REBOOTED! Anyways thanks for your answer in case it happens again.

Comment: No problem, Im glad it help you. The best way to protect yourself from viruses it use two account on the same computer, one is administrator with strong password and working account as  a standard user. This way your operation system will be in read-only state for viruses.